# What is the name of this construction "something-o-something"?

Tags: grammar

In the phrase "franco-prussian", what is the name of this construction using the contraction "something-o-something"?

Comment: [WP](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_nationality_prefixes): ***Nationality prefixes are prefixed combining forms** relating to a country, nationality, ethnicity, or language, or — most often — to more than one of these.*

Answer (score 1):

There's no "something-o-something" happening, it's just "something-something" and one of the things happens to end in an "o".

"o" isn't a joining word, it's part of the word "Franco" which means "pertaining to France" (from Latin I believe).  France may be the only country that gets this sort of word.  With other countries you'd just use the standard adjectival form of the country name, eg

"English-Prussian relations", "Italian-Prussian relations" etc.

Comment: Check out [the link I posted in the comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338453/what-is-the-name-of-this-construction-something-o-something#comment778567_338453): **Franco** (France), **Anglo** (English), **Hiberno** (Irish), **Russo** (Russian), **Luso** (Portugese), **Sino** (Chinese), and on and on. The question is which nationalities get an *-o* in their prefix combining form? What's the history behind this? Did Latin prefer its prefix combining forms to take a trailing `o`, a rule we imported into English? We certainly went out of our way with, eg, *Luso*.

Comment: **Indo**-Chinese...

Comment: @DanBron ah yes, good points.  I've definitely seen "Anglo" and "Sino" used, the others seem more obscure.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes. I think the interesting question isn't "which nationality prefixes are more common than others?", but "how and when and by what logic are nationality prefixes formed?". I did some cursory googling but I didn't find any interesting histories.